# Django - save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object - Formsets and CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm developing a small web app for timesheet control using Django 1.10.5 and I've came across an error that I cannot find the solution. I've search Stackoverflow and Google up and down and, even though I can find similar problems, none uses my approach (or I cannot find one similar).

I'm trying to extend the default User Model from django auth by creating a TUser Model with a One to One relation.

I've created a forms.py with two Forms - UserForm and AccountForm and a AccountInlineFormSet.

For adding the data to the database I've used a class based view approach, by creating a class AccountAddView(CreateView). Now, when saving, I keep getting `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object` even though I first save the main form and then save the inline form.

Here you can find the code:

`forms.py` https://github.com/hgpestana/chronos/blob/master/apps/account/forms.py

`views.py`
https://github.com/hgpestana/chronos/blob/master/apps/account/views.py

Any ideas on what the problem is? I'm a newbie on Django so I think it must be some stupid mistake, but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks =)